# Random Order of Messages in Telegram Bot which is integrated with Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram-bot

I have created Telegram Bot using Dialogflow free account.

Few weeks back it was working fine but now I am getting random sequence of sentences in case there are 2-3 sentences returned during single slot filling request or during fulfillment request.

However sequence is correct in case I am testing this on Web UI of Dialogflow console but while on Telegram sequence is not followed.